# IntelliJ Emulator does not scale properly

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-virtual-device, intellij-12

I got this legacy android project that ran by IntelliJ 12.8.

I cannot get the emulator to scaled properly, when I use a AVD with smaller screen, the emulator cannot display the whole content.
[image: small screen]

But if I use the AVD with big screen, the problem goes away.

[image: normal]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I updated the Android SDK and the newer version cannot scale the emulator properly.(in my case API 19, well, old project)
Fixed it by downgraded it.